# Study guide on calculus

Tags: calculus, reference-request, soft-question, advice

I have studied calculus until line integrals and double integrals,and  I think i quite understand the ideas and concepts,

but im afraid i haven't done as much excercises as i desired , and it has  left the feeling that i might have a shaky foundation in these subjects and not  the sufficient proficiency to study any further.

So what are some good and general problem set for me to have quick review on every subject starting from limits until the mentioned subject?

I have with me three textbooks, apostol's first volume,lithold's 3 volumes and G.H.Hardy's a course in pure mathematics.Which one would be suitable as a quick reminder of old subjects?

Comment: It is always risky giving advice to someone you don't know. You may get more suitable advice if you tell us (a) what book(s) you used in your previous study, (b) why you feel your foundation is 'shaky', and (c) your career objectives (e.g., PhD in abstract analysis, or scientist in a field that uses calculus to solve applied problems). That said, I'm somewhat familiar with the Apostol and Hardy books, and cannot easily imagine scenarios in which studying from either of them would be a waste of your time.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.I intend to go the pure maths route,and really want my foundations to be strong and reliable.n

Comment: I hope you are at a place where an instructor who knows your background can recommend a book. If this is self-study, I'd want a book with some worked problems or a student guide with a mix of worked problems and answers.